# How to get min value from specific clumn in another table in Power Query M (Power BI)?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have table in my data sources, which is loaded from database and which contains column with dates. I need got MIN and MAX value from this column and use values as parameter for creating another (computed) table in Power BI. How I can do it please?
I tried to use smething like `Start = Table.Min([MyTable], "SortTime")`, but this returns entire row, but i need only value from column "SortTime" ... Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Start = List.Min(MyTable[SortTime])
```

Comment: But this will only return the value. How can we get a table as a result?